# Post data to JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am not sure how to ask my question...

I have a problem with my form.  When I select "Qebele", it calls `getline()` in Line.js. I need to post any value to line.js and in line.js get this data to use it. How can I do this?

```
<form action="">
      <li><select id="rayon" onchange="getline();">
          <option value="">Select Rayon</option>
          <option value="rayon">Qebele</option>
      </select></li>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to make an AJAX call?

Comment: Are you looking for a jQuery or JavaScript solution? In any case, you will need to start by having a submit field on your form.

Comment: If you aren't submitting the form then it would be something like 
   
    function getline() {
          var myValue = document.getElementById("rayon").value;
          alert(myValue);
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the value of `#rayon` inside `Line.js` using the following code:

```
function getline()
{
    var theLine = document.getElementById('rayon').value;
    alert(theLine);
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbjxe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing a reference of the selected option's value to function getline, then continue from there.

For example, to pass a reference of the selected option's value to getline...

```
<form action="">
            <li><select id="rayon" onchange="getline(this.options[selectedIndex].value)">
                <option value="">Select Rayon</option>
                <option value="rayon">Qebele</option>
            </select></li>
</form>
```

Then, in Line.js, getline() does something based upon what was selected.

```
function getline(selectedValue){
    if (selectedValue == "something"){
             ... do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your asking.  Looking at your code  you should not use an inline function handler as the `'this'` keyword will refer to the window object.  If you use

```
document.getElementById('rayon').addeventlistener('change',getline);
```

in line.js the `'this'` keyword will refer to the select element with the id of 'rayon'.

Therefore

function getLine(){

alert(this.value)
}

will give you the value of rayon when you change the select to Qebel.

Obviously you will inplement your own logic to suit your needs.  It is very important not to use inline function calls as the `'this'` keyword has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this.value in onchange event.

`<form action="">
      <li><select id="rayon" onchange="getline(this.value);">
          <option value="">Select Rayon</option>
          <option value="rayon">Qebele</option>
      </select></li>
    </form>`

```
function getline(selectedValue){
  if(selectedValue == 'rayon'){
    //add your logic here
  }
}
```